# Debugging Web Application on Visual Studio 2010 after Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, visual-studio-debugging

I've deployed a web application in IIS7. I working with a client and trying to debug the website. I can access `myUrl/ApplicationName.aspx?user=user1`. I attached the process to Visual Studio using Tools -> Attached Process and have a breakpoint on the page_load. When I access `myUser/ApplicationName.aspx?user=user1/ApplicationName.aspx?user=user1`, I was expected to reached the breakpoint, but it never did. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to debug on the server from your local PC?

Comment: I installed Visual Studio on the server, so I am running it from there now. Once testing is completed, I will delete the code from the server.

Comment: Yikes. That doesn't sound right. What if you get another bug next week, are you going to do the same thing again? You better look at making your local environment identical to the server, or enabling remote debugging as mentioned in @GrokSrc answer.

Comment: I am trying to set it up now. I've been waiting on IT to open the ports number, but they've not done it. I thought my next best option is to install it on the server and debug it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remote Debugging needs to be enabled on the server.  Here are the instructions for setting it up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=vs.100).aspx

Once you have msvsmon.exe running and your firewalls configured correctly you should be able to hit your breakpoint.